# Mail function not responding to link

Tags: php

Could someone be able to help, I am trying to send an email once registration is conformed to an user where everything working fine except the link which is displaying as:

```
<a href=" http://176.35.232.280/appxailon.com/cgi-bin/admin/rego.php?passkey='.$activation.'">Activate account</a>
```

However I would like to show the `Activate account` only. Please help!!!

```
// Send the email:
$to = $email;
$subject = "Registration Conformation:Upperbit";
$from = 'Support@upperbit.com';
$body = "Hi"." $first ,"."\n\n";
$body .= "This is an automated message from Upperbit.Please dont reply to it."."\n\n";
$body .= "If you have recently signed up with us then please click on the below activation link to activate your account."."\n\n";
$body .= '<a href=" http://176.35.232.280/appxailon.com/cgi-bin/admin/rego.php?passkey='.$activation.'">Activation account</a>'."\n\n";
$body .= "if didn't intend to register with us please simply disregard this email."."\n"."-----------"."\n";
$body .= "Best regards,"."\n"."Upperbit Team";
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$body,$header);
```

Comment: `$headers` != `$header`

Comment: Your HTML in the PHP also contains `Activation account` not `Activate account` so `Activate account` would never be displayed..maybe this is out of date code?

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks man. Its just "Activate account" I wd like to display. Apology about any confusion created due to typo !!!

Comment: You need to change `Activation account</a>` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in mail send code

```
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

and in `rego.php`

```
$value = $_GET['passkey'];

if (isset($value)) {
    echo "Key is".$value;
}
else{
    echo "Error in setting paskey";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abdulla, much appreciated :-).